# Laplace Transform Damp Harmonic Motion

Tags: complex-analysis, inverse, laplace-transform

http://gyazo.com/19d18f085731c6dbc304fefdaece4f3c.png

I'm currently on (a) where so far I have gotten;

$  y'' + 2y' + 5y = f(t) $

Using Laplace transforms, I get;

$ Y(s)$ = $  F(s) + s+2\over(s^2 + 2s + 5) $

Completing square gives me;

$ F(s) + s + 2\over (s+1)^2 + 4) $ and subbing $ S = s + 1 $ and then splitting them so I can inverse Laplace them gets me;

$ F(s)\over(S^2 + 2^2)  $+ $ S\over(S^2 + 2^2) $ + $ 1\over(S^2 + 2^2) $

now I don't know how to apply an inverse laplace transform to the last term.

Comment: How do I apply laplace transform to f(t) though?

Comment: Oh I see from the link

Comment: I'm getting $  s^2 Y(s) - s + 2(sY(s) - 1) + 5Y(s) = F(s)  $, which results in  $  Y(s) = F(s) + s + 2/(s^2 + 2s + 5)  $. I'm pretty much stuck at the same spot again, I try completing the square but there's nothing in table that helps, I don't know what to do with F(s) term, just convert back to f(t)?.

Comment: So it would be $  F(s)/((s+1)^2 + 2^2) + s/((s+1)^2 + 2^2) + 2/((s+1)^2 + 2^2)  $. I see we can use 19 for the last term but what to do with others?

Comment: No I'm pretty lost now that the F(s) term is involved, didn't think I would be using it since I thought it'd be 0. Appreciate your help and patience.

Comment: Looked at the math.fsu.edu/~fusaro/EngMath/Ch5/ULTSDE.html link though their examples don't contain something about having a generic F(s) function in the transforms. Looked around online too and it says to decompose to a product of 2 terms but don't see how that would be possible for that term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given the differential equation:

$$\tag 1 y'' + 2y' + 5y = f(t), ~ y(0) = 1, y'(0) = 0 $$

Taking the Laplace Transform of $(1)$ and simplifying, we end up with the system:

$$Y(s) = \dfrac{1}{(s+1)^2 + 2^2} \left(F(s) + s + 2 \right)$$

We need to find the [*Inverse Laplace Transform*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf) for those three terms on the RHS.

For the general $F(s)$ term, we need to make use of the [*Convolution Theorem*](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/201.ev1.12w/201.ev1.12.Lec18.pdf).

The solution will be:

$$y(t) = (e^{-t} \sin t \cos t)*f(t)) + \left( \dfrac{1}{2}e^{-t}(2 \cos 2t - \sin 2t) \right)  + (e^{-t} \sin 2t)$$

Thus:

$$y(t) = \int_0^t (e^{-(t-v)} \sin(t-v) \cos(t-v))*f(v)~dv +  \dfrac{1}{2}e^{-t}(2 \cos 2t - \sin 2t)   + e^{-t} \sin 2t$$

Comment: Truly appreciate your patience and the depth of the help. For the first term with the general F(s) term, I put it as $  F(s)* 1/(s+1)^2 + 2^2  $ and then just tried to find a transform for  $  1/(s+1)^2 + 2^2  $ in the table to make it fit. How did you end up doing that, did you integrate, partial fractions perhaps to get it more general?

Comment: @Omar: We have $\dfrac{1}{(s+1)^2 + 2^2}$. If you look at item 19, we have $\dfrac{1}{2} e^{-t} \sin 2t = e^{-t} \sin t \cos t$, since $\sin 2 t = 2 \sin t \cos t$. Clear?

Comment: Ah perfect, that was the one I was looking at the most also to try to somehow modify it to get it to work, again thanks for your help.

Comment: You can probably leave it as shown without the simplification as that may make the convolution harder. However, it is also good to play with these and see the different forms. Regards

Comment: Oh wow now that I look at it once more, that's the solution I was coming up with but I thought the method to get it was mathematically wrong. I figured if I multiply the $  1/((s+1)^2 + 2^2)  $ by 2, apply the transform since then it fits perfectly with 19, and then divide it by 2 after the transform it would be work. But I thought that was just mathematically improper, thought the multiplication by 2 wouldn't translate during the transform, resulting in the wrong answer. But that clearly wasn't the case, cheers.